# How do I find survivors?

Tags: a-valley-without-wind

I've used the "search for survivors" guardian power and created "find survivor" missions, but how do I actually find the survivors? Do I just have to search everywhere and hope that I run in to them?  Is there any sort of map indication of where they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any mission, you have to go into that patch of the map (*press "E" when you are on the tile*) and have to find the entrance of the mission. Then you can rescue that survivor within that mission. This is normally done by escorting him out of the mission alive.

Those missions are also offered normally, without using any scrolls.

Comment: Is the entrance of the mission marked on the map, like any other mission?

Comment: Yes, it tells you in the tooltip when you walk past the entrance.

Comment: No, I meant the dungeon maps, located in the lower right in sidescrolling view.

Comment: I don't remember.. played this game months ago.

Comment: To answer my own question: Yes, they are.  However, if it's "Rescue a survivor from a deep cave" you'll have to pretty thoroughly explore the caverns before you find them.